# jQuery alert message box redirect upon click ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4, so how do I redirect the message box upon click ok back to index page?

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function errMsgBox() {
    alert("Please select the Correct Activity and Task");           
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "/Index") 
});
</script>
```

Comment: `window.location.href = 'whatever.aspx'`

Comment: ASPX is wrong. He is not using asp.net He's using ASP.net MVC.. it should be window.location = "controller/action" ex. "/Home/Index"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to use razor here anymore. Just use the window.location object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function errMsgBox() {
        alert("Please select the Correct Activity and Task");
        window.location = "/Home/Index";
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use such construction:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function errMsgBox() {
        alert("Please select the Correct Activity and Task");           
        window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
    });
```

Because in that case if you change your routes then it will use new route instead of specifying full route manually in Html. It's better to handle routes in one place, and it's not so good the hardcode them in Html, as in that case if route changes, then you need to update all hardcoded places.

And another point is parameters. If your action has parameter, it's also better to use Url.Action, as it will use parameters based on your route rules without hardcoding them too.

Comment: It's not good to mix JAVSCRIPT code with MVC code on VIEWS as it violates the RULE OF SEPARATION OF CONCERNS which MVC is all about. It's better to use pure javascript solution

Comment: The question is how to redirect to home page. It's not all about routes.. THE OP SAYS " so how do i redirect the message box upon click ok back to index page"

Comment: OP uses routes, and Home page is also MVC action and it has own route or default route. So it's about routes