# Is using Url.Action in Html\Javascript blocks is a good practice from MVC prospective?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

After discussion in comments for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205498/jquert-alert-message-box-redirect-upon-click-ok#comment31933302_21205554), it became curious for me - is it a good practice to use `Url.Action` in Javascript blocks of view to use the same routes that defined in RouteConfig instead of hardcoding urls manually? Does it it violates MVC ideology about separation?

For example if I have some some javascript code block in view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateName(objName){
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ValidateName", "Signup")',
            data: objName,
            sucess: function(result){
                if (result == someGoodValue){
                    window.location = '@Url.Action("NextStep", "Signup")';
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid name");
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Is it a good practice to use Url.Action in such blocks?

**UPDATE**

My main concern is that if we hardcode urls in Html, javascript files, then if route name changed, it was moved to area, etc, then we need to replace all hardcoded urls manually, that's a bit of pain.

Comment: I certainly believes in using Url.Action rather than using hardcoded urls manually?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Allan Chua, mixing razor with ***application-level*** javascript is a bad idea.

However, you can have separate javascript files, rendered by razor, that set javascript variables which your application-level javascript can then use. For example:

JavaScriptRoutes.cshtml

```
var routes = routes || {};
routes.signup = routes.signup || {};
routes.signup.validateName = '@Url.Action("ValidateName", "Signup")';
routes.signup.nextStep = '@Url.Action("NextStep", "Signup")';
```

Usage:

```
<script>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("JavaScriptRoutes"); }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateName(objName){
        $.ajax({
            url: routes.signup.validateName,
            data: objName,
            sucess: function(result){
                if (result == someGoodValue){
                    window.location = routes.signup.nextStep;
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid name");
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

This does mean you can't bundle the razor-generated javascript with the application javascript. We use RenderPartial to load it in the view as fast as possible though. Now your application-level javascript can be moved out of the razor file into an external .js file, because it take no dependencies on razor at all. When your routes change on the server, the URL's will change automatically, there is no need to hard-code them.

Comment: Yes, exactly, what I'm talking about. We can move route urls to dedicated generated JavaScript file, so we can use generated constants, and not hardcoded urls. So, when we change Route, then this code will generate update urls, and we don't need to fix all Urls across the whole project

Comment: But you still don't want to have dependencies in your ***application blocks***. Make the application blocks use the vars generated by razor. I will also give a downvote for T4MvcJs. I tried it, and never liked it.

Comment: Thanks for agreeing with me @danludwig. +1 for you my friend.

Comment: T4MvcJs is just an example of way how we can use routes in external javascript files. We can also generate them like in your answer, which is good. The only reason that your code code will be filled manually, and we can use reflection to build such code dynamically on project build, and generate static javascript file for example

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov, generating these route javascript files can be complex and tricky. For example, what if your action takes parameters, like '/widget/edit/6'? Then your javascript route actually becomes a function instead of a var.

Comment: Yes, sure it won't resolve all problems, but it should make it a bit easier. Here is a link that I posted under second answer - http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/12/20/asp-net-mvc-javascript-routing.aspx. This mechanism generates javascript during build for routes as functions, in which you can send parameters, and they will return final url with these parameters.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov yes I've read that before too. It's just something I don't use because we always generate routes using T4MVC instead of magic Controller and Action strings. The way we do it, any routing errors are discovered at build time rather than at text-tranformation-time or runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I had been developing applications for movie producers around the world. I'm going to tell you frankly. It's not a good idea to MIX MVC(Razor/ASP) view code with your JavaScript. The last thing you want to do is to VIOLATE THE SEPARATION OF CONCERNS WHICH MVC FOCUSES.

HERE ARE THE ADVANTAGES THAT SUPPORTS MY CLAIM: 
       1). If you separate all your javascript from html. Multiple developers can work on both of them at the same time (Advantage that MVC want's to provide). 
       2). If you put all your javascript on a separate file. You can cache them on the client's browser and thus resulting on a faster web page load time (http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/03/build-fast-loading-mobile-website/)
       3). You can also minify the javascript file which also results on faster load time.

By the way you can use hidden fields to store the Target URL and it's parameter(on JSON FORMAT). so you can access them on your javascript if ever you need to AVOID HARDCODING. What really bad is to mix up JavaScript with the VIEW(ASPX/RAZOR) code.

Comment: Yes, agree. But we can use different approaches to generate Javascript files with Urls based on routes and use it from external javascript : like T4MvcJs - http://t4mvcjs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MvcApplication/Scripts/T4MvcJs/T4MvcJs.js or some custom approaches like - http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/12/20/asp-net-mvc-javascript-routing.aspx . So the main my idea that hardcoded url shouldn't be present in Html\Javascript file, but generating this urls based on route should.

Comment: Yes, we can use different approach. but why not choose the one with more advantages? WEB IS A VERY COMPETITIVE MARKET AND YOU NEED TO PRODUCE THE BEST RESULTS FROM THE MOST APPROPRIATE SOLUTIONS AVAILABLE FOR YOU TO SURVIVE ON THIS COMPETITIVE BUSINESS.

Comment: I don't get what advantage in url hardcoding... It's no about using the same View, and we can also use external Javascript file, but we don't need to hardcode that url. If we want to use them in separate file, then we can generate these urls in View\generated javascript file, so it won't affect performance and also will be cached by browser.